# Nonlinear Black-Scholes model Vs linear Black-Scholes

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, european-options, black-scholes-pde, black-scholes-merton

I am working on a project related to Nonlinear ***BS*** partial differential equation, with terms for transaction costs and/or discrete hedging.
I have two questions:

1. Is there any exact solution to the **Nonlinear BS** equation?
2. I have read a paper which numerically solved a **Nonlinear BS** and compared results with **Linear BS**. Nonlinear BS is supposed to be giving different option price than Linear one. Why should we compare them ? [the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122108000783)

Lastly, as I am working on a project , it will be extremely helpful if you can provide some references that backs your statements.

Answer (score 3):

In general you have don't have an exact solution for the non linear equation - so you have to use numerical methods. Have you seen this [Non linear option pricing](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sIfNBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) book. It covers the topics that you mentioned.

People generally do compare the prices produced by non traditional models to the traditional ones - the purpose could be to benchmark the model output, understand/locate the regions where the prices differ, or to demonstrate the superiority of the new model etc.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. Still I needed a more accurate answer for the second question. Nonetheless,Thank you.

Comment: thanks! by the looks of it, the author is trying to demonstrate that the difference to Black Scholes is economically significant, and varies by maturity etc., so the non-linear models are informative/value adding in a sense